# Compiling java program using javac from command prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt, javac

I have new laptop on which I have installed jdk1.8.0_91 and jre1.8.0_91.
Both are in the "C:\Program Files\Java" folder.
I have NOT set any classpath or any environment variables.
I wrote a a HelloWorld.java program and saved it in "C:\my Data"   folder.
I then went to Command Prompt using cmd.
Then  I changed the current directory to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin"  ..since here is the javac.exe

and then tried to compile my HelloWorld program and its giving the following error -

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin>javac -sourcepath C:\my Data\HelloWorld.java
javac: invalid flag: Data\HelloWorld.com
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I am not sure whether I am correctly using the "sourcepath" or not...

How should I tell the compiler where my source file is ?(and I want to resolve this without setting any classpath or any environment variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead...

```
javac -sourcepath "C:\my Data" "C:\my Data\HelloWorld.java"
```

The `sourcepath` parameter allows you to specify the DIRECTORY where source files will be found. As per the javac command line output:

> -sourcepath  Specify where to find input source files

The parameter after that specifies the actual Java files to compile. You will need " around the parameters, given that your paths have spaces in them. Avoid spaces in your paths where ever possible to avoid this issue.

Comment: Hi Mano,When I am executing the class file using java.exe ...its again giving me an error ...can u please assist....just one more time :)... C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin>java C:\myData\HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\myData\HelloWorld

Comment: You don't call it like that. You call it via its fully qualified classname e.g. `java com.example.HelloWorld`. You'll have to replace my example classname here with your own. Bear in mind, you may need to point java at where the class file is e.g. `java -cp directory/where/classfiles/exist com.example.HelloWorld`

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the source path in quotes so that the command line processes it as a single argument. The source path must also be the directory in your case, not the file:

```
javac -sourcepath "C:\my Data"
```

Comment: Hi AR, I tried the quotes but still giving.. javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Answer (score 1):

-sourcepath is a PATH, you are giving a file name that's not a java file, that's not valid. From the docs:

**-sourcepath *sourcepath***

```
Specify the source code path to search for class or interface
definitions. As with the user class path, source path entries are
separated by colons (:) and can be directories, JAR archives, or ZIP
archives. If packages are used, the local path name within the 
directory or archive must reflect the package name.
```

[EDIT: OP changes the file name to .java in the question, as the other answer noted, it needed quotes.]

Answer (score 0):

Path C:\my Data\HelloWorld.java has space in it hence the error.

Please enclose path in "" (double quotes)

Comment: Thanks Anand for taking out time and replying ..but it was the wrong syntax I was using ...this worked fine ...javac -sourcepath "C:\my Data" "C:\my Data\HelloWorld.java"